# MYSQL Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: Upon multiplying

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a monthly income column. I need to get the Annual Income, so I tried multiplying monthly-income to 12.

I already tried casting it to UNSIGNED or CHAR. BUT I STILL GET THE SAME ALERT/ERROR

THE Query goes like this:
for example

```
monthly=20,000
SELECT monthly*12 from ...
```

The output should be `240,000`. I can't get that output thus getting that mysql alert/error:

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '20,000'.

Comment: ' monthly=20,000' - does this mean monthly datatype is text/varchar/char?

Comment: Decimal point vs. comma?

Comment: I forgot to declare the datatype, my bad. It's varchar.

Comment: try `replace(monthly, ',', '')*12`

Comment: Thanks @Nick. replace function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove comma before doing arithmetic operation, if monthly is text datatype

```
SELECT cast(replace(monthly, ',', '') as decimal(5,2)) * 12 from table
```